# Perl ==/eq looks for value or type?

Tags: perl

```
 65 sub is_in_array {
 66     my ($item, $arr) = @_;
 67     print $item . "\n";
 68     foreach(@$arr) {
 69         print $_ . "\n";
 70         if ($_ == $item) {
 71             return 1;
 72         }
 73     }
 74     #if (grep {$_ == $item} @$arr) {
 75     #    return 1;
 76     #}
 77     return 0;
 78 }
```

in @$arr it has

```
1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d  
c55e479d1a9befb605a84d0784afb277
```

$item that i have tried:

```
1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d  
c55e479d1a9befb605a84d0784afb277  
fb145f34ad73cb48a47ecdc4ccff52d9  
4766b07e6677ebadde51f6b281076283
```

they all return 1 but they should return 0 for the bottom two

anyone know why they are all returning 1?

---

it return 0 for  (and when i changed it to eq instead of ==)

```
7a90d765785b87238c3c33d9ec28fa44  
65153ae422d82c745656e7bca92edf20
```

I am so confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had added `use strict` and `use warnings` you would have found out for yourself by seeing the error message:

```
Argument "1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at stack.pl line 31.
```

So, replace `==` with `eq`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @array = ('1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d', 'c55e479d1a9befb605a84d0784afb277');
my $item = '1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d';
foreach(@array) {
    if ($_ eq $item) {
        print "Match found : $_\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Match found : 1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d
```

Answer (score 3):

`==` is a numeric equals operator.  When you use it on something that isn't a number, it gets a number from the leading digits, using 0 if there are none.  Use `eq` instead for string equals.

Note that when `==` uses something that isn't just a number, it will give a warning; you should always enable warnings to help you find problems like this.

Answer (score 3):

Both operators compare values, not types.  But `==` compares numbers, and `eq` compares stringwise, and both will by default try to convert your values to the type they compare.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `eq`  when you're comparing strings.

```
70         if ($_ eq $item) {
71             return 1;
72         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code:

```
my @arr = qw/1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d c55e479d1a9befb605a84d0784afb277/;
sub is_in_array {
    my ($item, $arr) = @_;
#   print $item . "\n";

    foreach(@$arr) {
#       print $_ . "\n";
        if ($_ eq $item) { # use eq instead of ==
            return 1;
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I got two items from your example:

> 1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d
>   c55e479d1a9befb605a84d0784afb277
>   fb145f34ad73cb48a47ecdc4ccff52d9
>   4766b07e6677ebadde51f6b281076283

and this worked fine:

```
print 'First'  if is_in_array('1de990354c913358c7d471b3dd6f1c6d', \@arr);
# Second won't be printed
print 'Second' if is_in_array('fb145f34ad73cb48a47ecdc4ccff52d9', \@arr);
```

You get this result `they all return 1 but they should return 0 for the bottom two` therefore you should check your $item value carefully

Comment: `print`ing a variable does *not* change its value to `undef`